# Is there a way to use variable inside the index of an array in response assertion?

Tags: arrays, jmeter

I have a json response. I am using json assertion where in one of the keys I have a big array.  I pass Json path as $.value.page[9999].hash. Now I want to have a variable value instead of 9999. How can I use variable instead of 9999. I tried to use variable generated in beanshell post processor. But I failed. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [eval()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and [evalVar()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar) functions to extract what you want:

```
 ${__eval($.value.page[${index}].hash)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) for this

> The V (variable) function returns the result of evaluating a variable name expression. This can be used to evaluate nested variable references (which are not currently supported).
>
> For example, if one has variables A1,A2 and N=1:
>
> `${A1}` - works OK
>
> `${A${N}}` - does not work (nested variable reference)
>
> `${__V(A${N})}` - works OK. `A${N}` becomes `A1`, and the `__V` function returns the value of `A1`

So you can come up with something like:

```
${__V($.value.page.[${page}].hash)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)